# Python 2.7x: How do I convert int of lets say 4.5 to 4.50

Tags: python-2.7

I am new (like 2 weeks) trying to learn Python 2.7x.
I am trying to do a basic program that has a user input a cost of a meal and it outputs how much it would be with a .15 tip.  I want the output to look like 23.44 (showing 2 decimals)

My code:

```
MealPrice = float(raw_input("Please type in your bill amount: "))
tip = float(MealPrice * 0.15,)
totalPrice = MealPrice+tip
int(totalPrice)

print "Your tip would be:               ",tip
print "Yout total bill would be:       ",totalPrice
```

my output:
Please type in your bill amount: 22.22
Your tip would be:                3.333
Yout total bill would be:        25.553

Answer (score 3):

You want to format your float value for printing only; use formatting:

```
print "Your tip would be:               {:.2f}".format(tip)
print "Your total bill would be:        {:.2f}".format(totalPrice)
```

The `.2f` is a [formatting mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) specification for a floating point value of 2 digits after the decimal.

You need to **remove** the `int()` call to preserve those digits after the decimal. You don't need to call `float()` so much either:

```
MealPrice = float(raw_input("Please type in your bill amount: "))
tip = MealPrice * 0.15
totalPrice = MealPrice + tip

print "Your tip would be:               {:.2f}".format(tip)
print "Your total bill would be:        {:.2f}".format(totalPrice)
```

Demo:

```
Please type in your bill amount: 42.50
Your tip would be:               6.38
Your total bill would be:        48.88
```

You can further tweak the formatting to align those numbers up along the decimal point too.